# While parsing Json using JsonReader I am getting SSLProtocolException

Tags: android, ssl, android-parser, jsonreader

I am trying to parse a json response with JsonReader so that I can directly use Inputstream to parse it.
But I am getting a exception.
Logcat:

```
02-04 18:30:54.515: W/System.err(1695): javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x36d690: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read_byte(Native Method)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:765)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readLine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:660)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.ChunkedInputStream.readChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:77)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:45)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:157)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:225)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:178)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:174)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:255)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:825)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:1045)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:784)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.objectValue(JsonReader.java:766)
02-04 18:30:54.525: W/System.err(1695):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:380)
```

How can I resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709176/1434631

Comment: Please, make proper questions. You should post your Java code that makes use of the library and the JSON response you want to parse.